# При включении TRIM для SSD в linux файловая система доступна только для чтения

Tags: linux, ssd

Установил KDE-neon на SSD и при добавлении опции `discard` в `fstab` после перезагрузки система входит в emergency mod. При попытки редатирования `fstab` через nano пишет что система доступна только для чтения.
В хелпе Ubuntu написано что в новых версиях ядер добавлять `discard` уже не обязательно, TRIM запускается автоматически, так ли это?
SSD - Transcend 360S [TS128GSSD360S]

Comment: после загрузки в emergency корень вполне может находиться в реад-онли. перемонтируйте его `mount / -o remount,rw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно убрать `discard` из `/etc/fstab`, а если очень надо TRIM, то можно в `/etc/rc.local` вписать следующее:

```
#Run “fstrim” at boot
LOG=/var/log/trim.log
echo “Time: $(date)” >>$LOG
fstrim -v / >>$LOG
echo “Time: $(date)” >>$LOG
```

Comment: Подскажите если ФС заблочилась после discard можно как то ее сделать доступной для записи или в этом случаее только систему переустанавливтаь?

Comment: попробовать загрузиться с любого LiveCD, смонтировать вручную ФС и отредактировать `fstab`. По-большому счету установочный диск - это тоже LiveCD и он позволяет загрузиться в recovery mode и то-же подправить `fstab`

Comment: @Бориc я пробовал через LiveCD тоже нельзя сохранять.

Comment: @Bleser: монтируйте вручную - не через файловый менеджер: просто в консоли набираем mount /dev/sda /mnt